# Can't interact with UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am making a Facebook like Slide-To-Right Menu. My problem is I can't interact with the rear UIView. Here is my code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *leftSidebarViewController;


self.leftSidebarViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"left"];
[self.navigationController.view.superview insertSubview:self.leftSidebarViewController.view
                                           belowSubview:self.navigationController.view];
[self.leftSidebarViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use one of the many open source implementations?

Comment: @Wain Cause they somehow don't work for me, I have a UINavigationController and a UITabBarController, either one of them causes problems. Or do you know a good one?

Comment: I have used https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/tree/master/ECSlidingViewController

Comment: I used this one (inside a tabbar controller with a navigation controller like in your case) https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to build your own see this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

It goes through the process in detail and should help you be able to fix your problem. I opted to use the third party library mentioned at the top of the tutorial due to time constraints.

Good luck!